# Function returning sum of even numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

So the prompt I was given was "Write a function that is given an array of ints and returns the sum of the even numbers in the array. The function is not given the length of array, but the last number in the array is -1. For example, if the array contains {2,3,5,4,-1} the function returns 6. Use the header int sumEven(int myArray[]). "

and the code I've written so far is

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumEven(int myArray[]){

int sum = 0;

for (int i=0; i++;){

if (myArray[i] >=0) {
    sum+=myArray[i];
}
}
return sum;

}
```

But it keeps returning back zero's? I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Because `i++` (when `i` is `0`) will be evaluated as `false`, for loop won't run at all.

Answer (score 4):

The typical order of parameters to a for() loop are like so:

`for(<initialize variable>; <end condition>; <increment variable>)`

In your example, you have the `i++` as your second parameter to the for loop, which is incorrect. It will return 0 (*since i starts as 0, and i++ is post-increment, so it returns 0 and then increments to 1*) and your for loop will exit immediately, since 0 evaluates to false.

Instead, replace the end condition with the end condition you've described: `myArray[i] != -1`. You should also include a check to see if the number is even before adding it to sum, which can be done by checking to see if the remainder when divided by 2 is 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumEven(int myArray[]){

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0; myArray[i] != -1; i++){
        if(myArray[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += myArray[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sumEven(int arr[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    // int len = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));  // Since this will not work for all cases.
    // auto len = end(arr) - begin(arr);
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] >= 0; i++) {
        if(arr[i]%2==0)
            sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `end(arr) - begin(arr);` won't work either. Note `arr` is just a pointer, not array. Have you tried your code?

Comment: @WhozCraig : Agree, thanks for pointing out it. I have edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Done :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `for` loop. You should change the `for` loop to `for (int i=0; ; i++)` and you should also add a `break` statement to exit the `for` loop.

```
using namespace std;

int sumEven(int myArray[]){

int sum = 0;

for (int i=0; ; i++){

    if (myArray[i] >=0) {
        sum+=myArray[i];
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
return sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the

```
for (int i=0; i++;){
```

make no iterations, cause condition to continue loop is "i++" - which is initialy zero.

Replace it with following for example

```
for (int i=0; i < array_length; i++;){
```

Comment: No, there's no `array_length`.

Comment: I see :), but it should be. How you going to going through the array without knowing it`s size?

Comment: OP mentioned it. "The function is not given the length of array, but the last number in the array is -1."

Comment: ok, missed it. In this case the right solution is already provided: 
for (int i=0; ; i++){

Comment: WhozCraig, you missed new ";" in the line :)

Comment: But, I'm voting for solution from Geoffrey Tucker. It looks better.